# How to generate image of graphics for data from Microsoft SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following example table:

```
Dt                      Value1   Value2  Value3 ...
2008-12-01 12:34:00     100.1    0.123   43
....
```

Is there any way by using TSQL to generate trend graphics as image such as jpg? Or do I need Reporting service to do it? I need to do it TSQL so that the daily trend images can be generated in a scheduled job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
1. Write a console programm which will connect to SQL and generate jpg with trends for your table
2. Run this programm with [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046(SQL.90).aspx) (you can pass some params also)

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell 'trendsgen.exe [param1], [param2]'
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you can schedule more than just T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

You'll need reporting services to do this.

You can schedule a job to use reporting services however.

Comment: cool. I guess using C# to generate jpg. I have never done that. Any information on this topic?